# Function pointers to non static member functions

Tags: c++, function, pointers

Error:

```
C:\testa\game.cpp|147|error: no matching function for call to 'game::register_handler(PacketFamily, PacketAction, 
<unresolved overloaded function type>)'|
```

Heres part of the code since it's too big.

I had to typedef handler_callback inside class game otherwise one of the two would be undefined for the other.

game.h

```
class game
{
typedef bool (game::*handler_callback)(PacketReader  reader);
public:
bool default_handler_init (PacketReader reader);
void register_default_handlers();
void register_handler(PacketFamily family, PacketAction action,handler_callback        callback);
};
```

game.cpp

```
 void game::register_default_handlers()
{
    register_handler(PACKET_F_INIT, PACKET_A_INIT,default_handler_init);

}

void game::register_handler(PacketFamily family, PacketAction action,handler_callback     callback)
{
handlers.insert(std::make_pair(std::make_pair(family, action), callback));
}
```

Comment: post a small complete example as well as complete error me

Comment: Where is `line 147`?

Comment: it's deleting the last part of my error

Comment: typedef bool (game::*handler_callback)(PacketReader  reader);

Comment: Maybe the compiler has no idea what a `PacketReader` is at that point in the file. You didn't post it, so we also don't know what is.

Comment: im sure it does know im sure the code i posted is sufficient.

Comment: @user3810737 - Compiles with no errors: http://ideone.com/QFyAtY

Comment: Maybe you're missing an ampersand. `register_handler(PACKET_F_INIT, PACKET_A_INIT, &default_handler_init);`

Comment: damn i was missing the ampersand as jtomscroeder said.
thanks all.

Comment: -1 for an unhelpful answer to Cheers and hth. - Alf's and PaulMcKenzie's questions.

Comment: @user3810737 - Now you see that any C++ error can be duplicated with a small example.  There is no excuse such as "the code is too big" if the problem is a syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expanded the OP's code to the following so that it would compile:

```
class PacketReader {};
class PacketFamily {};
class PacketAction {};
const PacketFamily PACKET_F_INIT;
const PacketAction PACKET_A_INIT;

class game
{
    typedef bool (game::*handler_callback)(PacketReader  reader);
public:
    bool default_handler_init (PacketReader reader);
    void register_default_handlers();
    void register_handler(PacketFamily family, PacketAction action, handler_callback callback);
};

void game::register_default_handlers()
{
    register_handler(PACKET_F_INIT, PACKET_A_INIT, default_handler_init);
}

void game::register_handler(PacketFamily family, PacketAction action, handler_callback callback)
{
    //handlers.insert(std::make_pair(std::make_pair(family, action), callback));
}
```

Compiling with g++ using the command `g++ -c -Wall -std=c++11 test.cpp` yields the following errors:

```
test.cpp: In member function ‘void game::register_default_handlers()’:
test.cpp:18:71: error: no matching function for call to ‘game::register_handler(const PacketFamily&, const PacketAction&, <unresolved overloaded function type>)’
     register_handler(PACKET_F_INIT, PACKET_A_INIT,default_handler_init);
                                                                   ^
test.cpp:18:71: note: candidate is:
test.cpp:13:10: note: void game::register_handler(PacketFamily, PacketAction, game::handler_callback)
     void register_handler(PacketFamily family, PacketAction action,handler_callback callback);
          ^
test.cpp:13:10: note:   no known conversion for argument 3 from ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’ to ‘game::handler_callback {aka bool (game::*)(PacketReader)}’
```

Anyway, to fix the problem, add `&game::` to the call to `register_handler`:

```
register_handler(PACKET_F_INIT, PACKET_A_INIT,&game::default_handler_init);
```